# Error in parseNamespace method using Extjs Proxy with Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to link my grid with a store, which is using a proxy to connect to some outside source. This is how I have set it up :

```
Ext.define('js.dmwf.PackageStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    model: 'js.model.Package',
    remoteFiler : false,
    remoteSort: false,

    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'json',
        url : 'mock/GetPackageListBB.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
    } });
```

However I am getting an error. Which is happening in the **parseNamespace** function in ext-all-debug.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined 
ext-all-debug.js:5043
Ext.ClassManager.parseNamespace ext-all-debug.js:5043
```

I have a feeling that I am missing an import or two. However i think i have everything :

```
        Ext.require([
            'Ext.data.*',
            'Ext.data.proxy.*',

            'Ext.data.reader.*',
            'Ext.grid.*',
            'Ext.tree.*',
            'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
            'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
            'Ext.ux.form.SearchField',
            'Ext.util.*',
            'Ext.state.*'

//            'Ext.ux.grid.Search'
        ]);
```

I have a fiddle too :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6jq

Comment: I guess proxy data should be something like this,   proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: (local ? url.local : url.remote),
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root:'data'
                },

Answer (score 0):

Proxy type needs to be `'ajax'`.

```
proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
...
}
```